# Does WSO 2 API Manager prevent to XSS and CRSF security error

Tags: wso2

I'm researching WSO2 API Manager and I discover that if I use WSO2 API Publisher and API Store, I would meet XSS and CSRF security errors. With XSS, I see that WSO2 didn't encode HTML character input. With CSRF, I see that WSO2 didn't create token when I request from client to server and vise versa.
Does everyone know how to config WSO2 to prevent these security error or how to fix them.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We fix these type of security issues in our next release  AM V 1.7.1. You can expect it in 3rd week of September.

Answer (score 3):

On our side, there are a few things we do when publishing/consuming APIs via the API Publisher and API Store:

1. Set the `Transports` property to just `HTTPS` so that we can limit API availability to just `HTTPS`.
2. For each `HTTP` method, we set the `Auth Type` to either `Application`, `Application User` or both, but never `none`. This will force the client to utilize the WSO2 [Access Token](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM170/Working+with+Access+Tokens#WorkingwithAccessTokens) scheme to invoke the APIs hosted on the API Store.
3. On the client side, we have been invoking the [Token API](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM170/Token+API) to generate and renew user and application access token so that we don't have to manually re-generate keys in the API Store.
4. Utilize API in-sequence to escape special characters.

Comment: Dear isim, I mean security issues such as XSS and CSRF in WSO2 API Publisher and API Store Portal, so I accept the answer of Ratha. If we use API from WSO2 API Manger, we should use as your suggest.

Comment: @LeVanDuc So I guess you are referring to the API Publisher and API Store *themselves* that are vulnerable to security issues then. If you are interested, you can find their source under the `repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps` folder.